# Get Count for Generic Repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to get the total number (count) for a given field from an index using a generic repository. The index mapping is huge and I do not wish to have an equivalent mapping on the Springboot side. The query is extremely simple;

```
http://localhost:9203/type_index/_count?q=person.name:john;
```

Should I have a generic class for the repository?

Can I use the *@Query* annotation?

How do I define which type and index that the repository should go to? Normally, this is done by the *@Document(indexName="type_index)* annotation on the Entity class but in this case, I will not have one.

```
@Repository
public interface GenericElasticsearchRepository<T, ID> extends ElasticsearchRepository<T, ID> {

     @Query("{\"bool\": {\"must\": [{\"match\": {\"person.name\": \"?0\"}}]}}")
     long countByName(String name);

}
```

When I use the above code, I am getting the following error;

```
ElasticSearchConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class java.lang.Object!
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As for building a query method without having the entity you could go for a custom implementation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior).

Define an interface (not extending ElasticsearchRepository) like

```java
interface CountByNameRepository {
  long countByName(String name);
}
```

and an implementation (just typing this here, not using an IDE, ao there might be errors):

```java
public class CountByNameRepositoryImpl {

  private final ElasticsearchOperations operations;

  public CountByNameRepositoryImpl(ElasticsearchOperations operations) {
      this.operations = operations;
  }

  public long countByName(String name) {
      Query query = new CriteriaQuery(Criteria.where("person.name").is(name));
      return operations.count(query, IndexCoordinates.of("type-index"));
  }
}
```

Your respository then will need to extend bot `ElasticsearchRepository` and `CountByNameRepository`, Spring Data Elasticsearch will use the provided implementation.

I have the index name hard coded here, as I don't know where you have access to this. You might be able to pass it as a second parameter to the method, but this depends on your concrete use case.

Comment: Thank you @P.J.Meisch. I did not know about IndexCoordinates. This helped me big time.